# How to Write Generic Method parameter at Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

How can I write a generic method parameter at my interface method?

```
public <T extends Mail> T getById(HttpServletResponse response, <ID extends Object> ID);
```

This line gives me error:

```
<ID extends Object> ID
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how is this different than `public <T extends Mail> T getById(HttpServletResponse response, Object ID);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.

```
public <T extends Mail, ID> T getById(HttpServletResponse response, ID id) {
```

Note that `extends Object` is not a meaningful bound for a wildcard.  And declaring `ID` to be a wildcard on a single method is rarely helpful without any bounds.

Comment: I just want to use it as a trick. Instead of Object I want to see ID(I will add javadoc for my method to be more clear.) However I have a problem when I want to implement that method I want to use String (sometimes Integer) not an Object. How can I do that because it gives error?

Comment: There's no problem with declaring otherwise unbound types if it makes the code clearer.  That said, I am not sure what error you are getting... please post the code and error you see.

Comment: The only thing that method will be able to return is `null`. Could also just not return normally.